# Pandas - drop records if on specific column value is equal to previous record

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates

I have a dataframe like following (sorted by id, time and status):

| id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | 29.08.2023 12:39 |
| 111 | A | 29.08.2023 12:45 |
| 111 | B | 29.08.2023 12:47 |
| 111 | C | 29.08.2023 12:50 |
| 111 | A | 29.08.2023 12:50 |
| 112 | A | 29.08.2023 12:50 |
| 112 | B | 29.08.2023 13:09 |
| 112 | C | 29.08.2023 13:40 |
| 112 | B | 29.08.2023 13:50 |
| 112 | A | 29.08.2023 13:55 |

I need to remove remove repeats in status sequences but only for cases when status repeats in next to each other records. Meaning that id 111 can have multiple statuses == 'A', but I need to remove second 'A' if previous status in time also was 'A'.
So new table should be like this (remove second line with same status):

| id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | 29.08.2023 12:39 |
| 111 | B | 29.08.2023 12:47 |
| 111 | C | 29.08.2023 12:50 |
| 111 | A | 29.08.2023 12:50 |
| 112 | A | 29.08.2023 12:50 |
| 112 | B | 29.08.2023 13:09 |
| 112 | C | 29.08.2023 13:40 |
| 112 | B | 29.08.2023 13:50 |
| 112 | A | 29.08.2023 13:55 |

So in the end we have a unique sequences of statuses for each id without repeats.

Appreciate any help because I stuck with some very slow and blunt approach comparing each row with previous, but dataset is very huge, > 5M records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get difference of multiple columns shifted values and get rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df[['id','status']].ne(df[['id','status']].shift()).any(axis=1)]
print (out)
    id status         timestamp
0  111      A  29.08.2023 12:39
2  111      B  29.08.2023 12:47
3  111      C  29.08.2023 12:50
4  111      A  29.08.2023 12:50
5  112      A  29.08.2023 12:50
6  112      B  29.08.2023 13:09
7  112      C  29.08.2023 13:40
8  112      B  29.08.2023 13:50
9  112      A  29.08.2023 13:55
```